# dynamically update href/src attributes from manifest json

Tags: javascript, manifest

I am dynamically updating html src/href attributes from reading a manifest.json file.

But I'm pretty sure the way I do this is not following best practices. I cannot find anything on the subject.

What would be the ideal way of reading my manifest.json, for the purpose of updating the links in my html ?

What I do :

```
  <link id="maincss" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <script id="mainscript"></script>
  <script>
    function readTextFile(file, callback) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("/dist/manifest.json", function(text){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        document.getElementById('mainscript').setAttribute('src', '/dist/'+data.main[1]);
        document.getElementById('maincss').setAttribute('href', '/dist/'+data.main[0]);
    });
  </script>
```

You can see that once I read the file, I'm setting the src attribute for the javascript, and the href attribute for the css.

My manifest.json :

```
{"main":["mycss.798d79ab87daa2i3df123.css","main.f8aaae15e396b637e82e.js"]}
```

Comment: I would use a template language for your index.html file and pre-render those script and style imports on the server.

Comment: I disagree. Importing an entire library just so you can reference the files opposed to set them via JavaScript isn't worth it. That's like the old days when people would import jquery just so they could do `$(...)` instead of `document.getElementById` (or whatever selection type you're after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to externalize your JavaScript and CSS so you can change them outside of your app without having to do a redeploy (or something to that effect).

I would argue there are cleaner solutions for this use case, but given your setup, I'd just clean it up a little bit and make it a little more flexible.

The first thing I would fix is this:

`<link id="maincss" rel="stylesheet">`
`document.getElementById('maincss').setAttribute('href', '/dist/'+data.main[0]);`

This may not be an issue, but this is really just locking you down to a single css file. What if you need to add another file? or maybe it's a different file type (like a font-style).

With that being said, I would ditch the placeholder elements completely. Obviously, the way you are referencing the placeholders (mainscript, maincss) would be ditched as well.

For starters, I would refactor your `json` file to be more scalable, then, I would essentially create a "mini module loader"

Here's what I would do:

```
// Fake HTTP Get that returns your manifest file
const fakeGetRequest = () => {
  return [{
      "type": "link",
      "src": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    },
    {
      "type": "script",
      "src": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    }
  ];
}

// Helper function to centralize the creation of the reference tag
const createRef = (src, type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'script':
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = src;
      return script;
    case 'link':
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.href = src;
      return link;
  }
  return null;
}

// Your manifest.json
const manifest = fakeGetRequest();

// Iterate over your manifest and append things where you want them
manifest.forEach(item => {
  const ref = createRef(item.src, item.type);
  switch (item.type) {
    case 'link':
      document.head.appendChild(ref);
      break;
    case 'script':
      document.body.appendChild(ref);
      break;
  }
});
```

This would enable to add as many script/css references you want and your code will know how to append them at all times, no matter how many you want to append. Since your manifest file is now configurable and you have code in your page that knows how to translate it into something meaningful, supporting different file types like images or whatever else you wanted to throw in there would a matter of adding that type to your code so it knows what to do with it.

I only have two properties in the manifest (`src` and `type`), but realistically, you'll probably want something like order (maybe there is a dependency that needs to be referenced first), another property for if you want it to be appended to the `head` or `body`, etc...

Long way of saying that I think what you have is fine, there really isn't much to improve there. The only thing you could significantly improve on is scalability (if needed).